# Can a Google Cloud function be triggered on complete of 2 or more other functions?

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I wasn't sure what to search for as I don't which subject matter this fits in.

What I have in mind is sort of like JS Promise.all([...]).then() but for cloud functions.

For ex. function A depends on the successful completion of functions B and C which are not aware of each other and run concurrently.

I assume something like this is not available natively?

The only thing I can think if is keeping some sort of persistent register and an intermediate function which fires on completion of both B and C and checks if the group has completed and triggers A when they have.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible with Cloud Functions alone.  The system is stateless - there is no "memory" of what happens with each function invocation.

What you would have to do is involve another product to retain state that would be responsible for triggering the third function after the first two complete.  One way to implement this is using a Firestore document to store the completion status of each function.  Functions B and C will have to agree on some share unique ID that identifies their work.  That ID could be used as the ID of the document in a collection that stores the completion state of each function - the functions would have to write their status to that doc before completion.  Then you could write a Firestore trigger that gets invoked when a document in that collection changes.  The function would then examine the document to see if B and C are complete, and process to run A.

Comment: I suspected that much, but didn't know enough about GCP. Thanks anyway.